# How to secure API in wso2 API Manager with API Keys

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I'm using the wso2am-4.0.0 for api manager. I'm not able to invoke api secured using API Keys or Basic Auth.The OAuth2 is working fine. When I invoke the api using API keys or with basic auth , it gives the following error message.
{
"code": "900902",
"message": "Missing Credentials",
"description": "Invalid Credentials. Make sure your API invocation call has a header: 'Authorization : Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN' or 'Authorization : Basic ACCESS_TOKEN' or 'apikey: API_KEY'"
}
Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable the `Basic` and `Api Key` options for the API in the `Application Level Security` section of the `Runtime configurations` of the `Publisher Portal`.

[image]

After making the above change and re-deploying the API, you will be able to invoke the API using `Basic Auth` and `Api Keys`.

You can refer the documentation for [Securing APIs with API Keys](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/design/api-security/api-authentication/secure-apis-using-api-keys/#using-api-keys-to-secure-an-api)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did this setting as per the documentation link.But while invoking the API , getting the below error {
    "code": "900902",
    "message": "Missing Credentials",
    "description": "Invalid Credentials. Make sure your API invocation call has a header: 'Authorization : Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN' or 'Authorization : Basic ACCESS_TOKEN' or 'apikey: API_KEY'"
}. Am I missing any configuration.Buth OAuth2 authentication isworking .

Comment: It's working now. After configuring, I was saving instead of 'Save and Deploy'. So the config changes are not deployed.